# Ubuntu stops showing movie after idle time

Tags: 14.04, intel, idle

I'm running Ubuntu 14.04, and when I am watching a movie, after 10-20 minutes the NUC stop casting picture to my tv, and I need to wiggle the mouse to get the screen back on.
I disabled the screen suspend to *never*, but it won`t work. 
How can I fix it? :)

Comment: Is this askubuntu.com/a/524847/72216 a solution to you? It keeps the computer and screen awake after pressing a key combination, and afterwards disables it again with the same key combination. You don't even need to alter the settings for screen/sleep settings.

Comment: I think I`ll drop that, that`s to much for me, I`m afraid I`ll do something wrong...

Comment: Really, if you keep to the instructions, there is not much that can go wrong. even if you won't manage to stop the script, it *will* after log out/in.

Comment: Iknow, maybe I`ll try...

Comment: I`m doing it now, I`m at school and teamviewer my NUC :P I`ll report back when I get home :)

Comment: This is really hard... I don`t understand anything of it -.-

Comment: I didn`t get it to work, so I giving up...

Comment: Don't try this in teamviewer, hard to say where is the problem then. If it doesn't work at home, please let me know where "it hurts". It should be really simple.

Comment: I'll try when I get home. How do I know if it don't work?

Comment: If you also use the toggle script, you will see a notification, mentioning the script either stops or starts.

Comment: Okey, I'll try:)

Comment: I think it works now:)

Comment: Perfect! Glad it works.